# Роутинг и ленивая загрузка

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue3

Во время установки дефолтного стартового проекта на `vue3` генерируется следующий пример:

```
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
  },
];
```

Вопрос:
Является ли ленивая загрузка роутинга стандартом программирования в данной среде или же ее необходимо использовать только в разрезе высоконагруженных компонентов?

Comment: Зависит от задач конкретного приложения.

Comment: а на что необходимо ориентироваться в этих задачах приложения - на нагруженность?
или есть еще какие то критерии?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под нагруженностью? Я бы скорее сказал, ориентироваться надо на "отзывчивость". Если для вашего приложения приемлемо, чтобы при переходе с одной страницы на другую происходила подгрузка этой страницы, то да, лучше делить на чанки. Если более подходящий сценарий - это подождать один раз подольше при инициализации приложения и потом работать без динамической подгрузки, тогда никакие динамические импорты вам не нужны. Смотрите на свои задачи.

Comment: Представь себе жителя далёкой бедной страны заходящего на твой сайт с убойно тормознутого модема с какого ни будь Pentium 4... Как думаешь каковы у него будут критерии? Я полагаю если не будет LazyLoad, то он явно не дождётся загрузки страницы.